# How to react to a language change in a dropdown database service

Tags: orbeon

I have a form with a dropdown selection for the municipalities.
Italian users see the italian names, german users the german names.
Changing the language of the form works smootly, the names are instantly updated.

```
<resource xml:lang="de">
     <gem>
        <label>Ansuchen an die Gemeinde</label>
        <hint/>
        <item>
            <label>Abtei</label>                        
            <value>6</value>
        </item>
        ...
     </gem>
</resource>  
<resource xml:lang="it">
    <gem>
        <label>Richiesta al Comune di:</label>
        <hint/>
        <item> 
            <label>Aldino</label> 
            <value>1</value> 
        </item>
        ...
     </gem>
</resource>  

<fr:dropdown-select1 xmlns:xxbl="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xbl" id="gem-control" bind="gem-bind">
    <xf:label ref="$form-resources/gem/label"/>
    <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/gem/hint"/>
    <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
    <xf:itemset ref="$form-resources/gem/item">
        <xf:label ref="label"/>
        <xf:value ref="value"/>
    </xf:itemset>
 </fr:dropdown-select1>
```

Now I saw in [populating a dropdown](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-builder/database-services.html)
that it is feasible to load the dropdown items from a database.
I tried this and it functions, but the actual solution has the little flaw of an extra control on the form.

I created in the database a table with the three fields `gem`, `lang` and `gembeschr`.
Example of the contents of the table:

```
gem    lang   gembeschr  
====== ====== =========    
 1     de     ALDEIN  
 1     it     ALDINO  
 ...
```

In orbeon  in the database service then I used the following select:
`SELECT gem, gembeschr FROM tablename where lang=<sql:param type="xs:string" select=""/>  order by gembeschr`

But in all the examples I saw so far, the changes in the dropdown react to a control change on the form.
So in the model I inserted the following `var` to establish the actual language of the form and used then this var in the calculate of a control:

```
<xf:var name="langmmm"> 
   <xxf:value value="xxf:get-session-attribute('fr-language')"/>
</xf:var>   

<xf:bind id="control-1-bind" name="control-1" ref="control-1" xxf:whitespace="trim" calculate="$langmmm"/> 

 <xf:output id="control-1-control" bind="control-1-bind">
     <xf:label ref="$form-resources/control-1/label"/>
     <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/control-1/hint"/>
     <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
 </xf:output>
```

And in the action then I specified this control in the observer:

```
 <xf:action event="xforms-value-changed xforms-enabled" ev:observer="control-1-control" if="true()">
     <!-- Service to call -->
     <xf:send submission="gemeindeliste-submission"/>
 </xf:action>
```

NB. I cannot change the visibility of control-1 to false(), because then the submission for the select will not be done anymore.

Is there a possibility to launch the select when the language of the form changes, without this additional control?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can, if you are ok with the database service returning all the languages at the same time. See [this doc for details](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-builder/advanced/services-and-actions/actions#internationalization).

Comment: Thanks for the quick help!
I tried the infos in the link and it works for the form load. Starting with the italian language in the summary form the dropdown values are in italian, and starting with german language the dropdown values are in german.  
My select is now without the where: `SELECT gem, lang, gembeschr FROM gemeindenlong order by gembeschr`.  
`/response/row[@lang = $fr-lang]` did not work for me. I used  
`<xf:var name="response-items" value="/response/row[lang=$langmmm]"/>`  
The react event now is `<xf:action event="xforms-ready" ev:observer="fr-form-model" if="true()">`

Comment: But changing the language in the form doesn't work. This looks ugly: the form changes, the dropdown values don't.  
So I suppose my implementation is too simplified to have a similar behaviour as with the dropdown values in the fr-form-resources instance,
where the `$form-resources` variable makes the magic: `<xf:itemset ref="$form-resources/gem/item">`
Is a similar behaviour feasable also with the dropdown values loaded from the database? Is there some example somewhere?  
Loading the dropdown values from a database would be beneficial for the maintenance in the long run

Comment: It is meant to work, and if it doesn't it's either misconfigured or a bug in Orbeon Forms.

Comment: The link does not work. But the info here pushed me towards datasets and basing itemset on `xxf:get-session-attribute('fr-language')`.

Comment: FWIW I updated the link to point again to the correct page.